# How to list the clauses inside a module in SWI-Prolog?

Tags: reflection, module, prolog, swi-prolog

SWI-Prolog has for example the [library(dcgbasics)](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=summary-lib-dcgbasics) for use with [DCGs](https://www.metalevel.at/prolog/dcg).

While referencing the module is easy with [`use_module/1`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=use_module/1), e.g.

```
:- use_module(library(dcg/basics)).
```

trying to use [`listing/1`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=listing/1) with it is not so easy.

```
?- listing(dcg:_).
true.

?- listing(dcgbasics:_).
true.

?- basics:listing.
true.
```

What is the correct way to get a listing of the clauses in `library(dcg/basics)`?

---

Follow up after answer given.

To list a specific clause, e.g. `blanks//0` the query is

```
?- listing(dcg_basics:blanks).
blanks(A, B) :-
    blank(A, C),
    !,
    D=C,
    blanks(D, B).
blanks(A, A).

true.
```

Comment: An (old fashioned) user friendly option is use XPCE: ` ?- edit(library(dcg/basics)).` and then ^C^N (i.e. open navigator).

Comment: @CapelliC Thanks. I don't use XPCE. I have about 8 editors and IDEs on my task bar now, not to mention others that don't rate a task bar slot, I don't think my brain has room for another.

Comment: It's a pity... IMO XPCE is a nice IDE, just a bit step to start with. I used a lot of them, in the past and still today, but when possible I do prefer simplicity, so in the end Firefox on localhost is my real IDE today.

Comment: @CapelliC Thanks for the nudge. It seems all of the more advanced SWI-Prolog users use it and lately I do find myself wanting the features of an IDE when using SWI-Prolog. I will give it a higher priority for learning, but not in the next few weeks. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use either:

```
?- dcg_basics:listing.
```

Or:

```
?- listing(dcg_basics:_).
```

The first argument of `use_module/1-2` is a file specification, not a module name. But listing the module contents requires the actual module name, which may be different (as it is the case here) from the module file basename. But how to find the module name from the file specification? In the particular case of SWI-Prolog:

```
?- absolute_file_name(library(dcg/basics), Path, [extensions([pl])]),
   module_property(Module, file(Path)).
Path = '/Users/pmoura/lib/swipl/library/dcg/basics.pl',
Module = dcg_basics.
```